# Getting an object within an object within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In Javascript I have an array of clients. Each client is an object that has inside an array of vehicles which are also objects. Now I need to get another array of objects named trabajos that should be nested inside the vehicles. All should be stored in the localStorage, but I am not sure how I should start getting the trabajos inside the vehicles. Here is how I gotten the first two parts.

```
function getClientes(){
let listaClientes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listaClientesLS'));
let clientes = [];

if (listaClientes == null) {
    clientes = [];
} else{
    listaClientes.forEach(obj =>{

        let objCliente = new Cliente(obj.nombre, obj.apellido1, obj.apellido2, obj.cedula, obj.telefono, obj.email);

        obj.listaVehiculos.forEach(objVehiculoTemp => {
          let objVehiculo = new Vehiculo(objVehiculoTemp.matricula,objVehiculoTemp.marca,objVehiculoTemp.modelo,objVehiculoTemp.anno,objVehiculoTemp.capacidad,objVehiculoTemp.kilometraje);

          objCliente.agregarVehiculo(objVehiculo);

        });

        clientes.push(objCliente);
    })
}

return clientes;
```

}

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `listaClientes`

Comment: The posted code is not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure I'm sorry if this is not the correct way of presenting it but I'm pretty new to OOP so I'm a bit lost....

Comment: The full repository is here https://github.com/aaronacuna/tareaParte    I tried copying the getClientes() result from the console but I can't copy it.

Answer (score 0):

The github repository (the question is not minimal) suggests jobs  ("trabajos") for a vehicle should be stored in the `listaTrabajos` array property of a vehicle object, placed there by the add job method (`agregarTrabajo`) of a the vehicle class, called from the job registration function `regTrabajo`.

But the vehicle class does not define the `agregarTrabajo` method. I expect `regTrabajo` throws an error when called. (Note errors on the console should be solved before anything else! You can ask a question about an error if you can't solve it.)

Add the `agregarTrabajo` method to the `Vehiculo` class, e.g.

```
class Vehiculo {
    constructor(....
        //... constructor function
    }
    agregarTrabajo (pObjTrabajo) {
      this.listaTrabajos.push(pObjTrabajo);
    }
}
```

Now the list of jobs can be accessed using the `listaTrabajos` property of the `objVehiculoTemp` argument of the function processing each vehicle in the post. I don't know what processing is required:

```
 obj.listaVehiculos.forEach(objVehiculoTemp => {
      let objVehiculo = new Vehiculo(objVehiculoTemp.matricula,objVehiculoTemp.marca,objVehiculoTemp.modelo,objVehiculoTemp.anno,objVehiculoTemp.capacidad,objVehiculoTemp.kilometraje);

     // process objVehiculoTemp.listaTrabajos

     objVehiculo.listaTrabajos =  objVehiculoTemp.listaTrabajos;  // FOR EXAMPLE

     objCliente.agregarVehiculo(objVehiculo);

});
```